# install pyquery on windows

Tags: python, installation, python-3.x

I want to install pyquery on windows. But i cant run setup.py install on the command line. Do you have any hint?

Comment: Did you got any error? Can you please post the log of your command line?

Comment: i go to bed now, sorry. i will do this next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you don't have lxml or setuptools installed

setuptools
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.6c11

lxml
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/2.2.2

Install them first and then try again, I just tried that, its working properly here.

Comment: i installed lxml but not setuptools. i will do this now. thanks.

Comment: i use Python 3.1.1 now. setuptools are only available until 2.6. :/

Comment: Unless I've missed something, pyQuery isn't available for Python 3 either. Python 3 is a new major version of Python which is incompatible in several significant ways with Python 2.0.

Comment: i use python 2.7.3 now. lxml are only available 2.6 and 3.0 and 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I could not install lxml on windows with either pip or easy_install. Complained "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

Tried installing Cygwin and MinGW but that was taking way too long

found out from [raidsan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9819303/482053) about unofficial precompiled windows binaries
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
installed and works fine now

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLE WORKING SOLUTION:

I download the tar file here pyquery-1.2.13.tar.gz (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery#downloads)

I extracted them a folder pyquery-1.2.13 then i pasted myscript.py to this folder pyquery-1.2.13 in my script i have these lines at the very top to include pyquery module and it works!

## import pyquery (this file is in pyquery-1.2.13 folder)

from pyquery import *

Done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using miniconda on Windows and here is how I installed pyQuery :

Download python miniconda from http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html
(if you need many libraries at once, consider installing anadonda instead)

Then from the commandline prompt, run the following commands:

```
conda install lxml
conda install setuptools
```

Grab the lastest pyQuery source from https://codeload.github.com/gawel/pyquery/zip/master  and unzip it to a directory.

Again from the commandline, go to this directory and run :

```
python setup.py install
```