# Setting up pyquery for python 2.7 for windows

Tags: lxml, pyquery

I am trying to setup pyquery,but is giving me a hard time.

There is .py file setup.py , which imports from `setuptools`

I also read lxml can be used instead of that ,i have installed lxml.

Could anyone guide me with this installation.I also did read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967662/install-pyquery-on-windows)

Comment: Please expand on "giving me a hard time". Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

PyQuery is just an api wrapper for lxml.

Once you get lxml installed you can easily install pyquery

I guess that your problem occur because setuptools try to install lxml and failed at compilation time

Comment: Hey, Just copied the folder to c:/python27/lib/site-packages. It works now . Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Added the folder Pyquery to to python27/lib/site-packages.

It works now.