# lxml install on windows 7 using pip and python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, lxml, pip

When I try to upgrade lxml using pip on my windows 7 machine I get the log printed below.

When I uninstall and try to install from scratch I get the same errors.
Any ideas?

> Downloading/unpacking lxml from
>   https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/l/lxml/l
>   xml-3.2.4.tar.gz#md5=cc363499060f615aca1ec8dcc04df331   Downloading
>   lxml-3.2.4.tar.gz (3.3MB): 3.3MB downloaded   Running setup.py
>   egg_info for package lxml
>       Building lxml version 3.2.4.
>       Building without Cython.
>       ERROR: Nazwa 'xslt-config' nie jest rozpoznawana jako polecenie wewnętrzne l ub zewnętrzne,
>       program wykonywalny lub plik wsadowy.
>
> ```
> ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed *
> ```
>
> *
>
> ```
> Using build configuration of libxslt
> D:\software\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distrib ution option: 'bugtrack_url'
>   warnings.warn(msg)
>
> warning: no files found matching 'lxml.etree.c' under directory 'src\lxml'
> warning: no files found matching 'lxml.objectify.c' under directory 'src\lxm l'
> warning: no files found matching 'lxml.etree.h' under directory 'src\lxml'
> warning: no files found matching 'lxml.etree_api.h' under directory 'src\lxm l'
> warning: no files found matching 'etree_defs.h' under directory 'src\lxml'
> warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'src\lxml\tests'
> warning: no files found matching 'pubkey.asc' under directory 'doc'
> warning: no files found matching 'tagpython*.png' under directory 'doc'
> warning: no files found matching 'Makefile' under directory 'doc' Installing collected packages: lxml   Found existing installation:
> ```
>
> lxml 2.3
>       Uninstalling lxml:
>         Successfully uninstalled lxml   Running setup.py install for lxml
>       Building lxml version 3.2.4.
>       Building without Cython.
>       ERROR: Nazwa 'xslt-config' nie jest rozpoznawana jako polecenie wewnętrzne l ub zewnętrzne,
>       program wykonywalny lub plik wsadowy.
>
> ```
> ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed *
> ```
>
> *
>
> ```
> Using build configuration of libxslt
> building 'lxml.etree' extension
> D:\software\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3  /GS- /DNDEBUG
> ```
>
> -Ic:\users\x\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_x\lxml\src\lxml\inc ludes -ID:\software\Python27\include -ID:\software\Python27\PC
>   /Tcsrc\lxml\lxml. etree.c
>   /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.obj
>       lxml.etree.c
>       c:\users\x\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_x\lxml\src\lxml\includes\etree_d
>   efs.h(9) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
>   'libxml/xmlversion.h': N o such file or directory
>       D:\software\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distrib ution option: 'bugtrack_url'
>         warnings.warn(msg)
>       error: command '"D:\software\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' fai led with exit status 2
>       Complete output from command D:\software\Python27\python.exe -c "import setu
>   ptools;**file**='c:\users\x\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_x\lxml\setu
>   p.py';exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'),
>   **file**, 'exec' ))" install --record c:\users\x\appdata\local\temp\pip-pyyuss-record\install-r ecord.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed:
>       Building lxml version 3.2.4.
>
> Building without Cython.
>
> ERROR: Nazwa 'xslt-config' nie jest rozpoznawana jako polecenie
>   wewnętrzne lub z ewnętrzne,
>
> program wykonywalny lub plik wsadowy.
>
> ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **
>
> Using build configuration of libxslt
>
> running install
>
> running build
>
> running build_py
>
> creating build
>
> creating build\lib.win32-2.7
>
> creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
>
> copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
>
> copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
>
> copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
>
> copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
>
> copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
>
> copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
>
> copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
>
> copying src\lxml_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
>
> copying src\lxml__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
>
> creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes__init__.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
>
> copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
>
> copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
>
> copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
>
> copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
>
> copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
>
> copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
>
> copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
>
> copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
>
> copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
>
> copying src\lxml\html_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
>
> copying src\lxml\html_html5builder.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
>
> copying src\lxml\html_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
>
> copying src\lxml\html__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
>
> creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron
>
> copying src\lxml\isoschematron__init__.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschema tron
>
> copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
>
> copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
>
> creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources
>
> creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
>
> copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng ->
>   build\lib.win 32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
>
> creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
>
> copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl ->
>   build\lib.win32-2 .7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
>
> copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl ->
>   build\lib.win32-2 .7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
>
> creating
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xsl
>   t1
>
> copying
>   src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_e
>   xpand.xsl ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron
>   -xslt1
>
> copying
>   src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_inclu
>   de.xsl ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xs
>   lt1
>
> copying
>   src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron
>   _message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schemat
>   ron-xslt1
>
> copying
>   src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron
>   _skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\
>   iso-schematron-xslt1
>
> copying
>   src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_x
>   slt1.xsl ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-
>   xslt1
>
> copying
>   src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt
>   -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
>
> running build_ext
>
> building 'lxml.etree' extension
>
> creating build\temp.win32-2.7
>
> creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
>
> creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src
>
> creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml
>
> D:\software\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
>   /MD /W3 /GS
>   - /DNDEBUG -Ic:\users\x\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_x\lxml\src\lxml\include s -ID:\software\Python27\include -ID:\software\Python27\PC
>   /Tcsrc\lxml\lxml.etre e.c
>   /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.obj
>
> lxml.etree.c
>
> c:\users\x\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_x\lxml\src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.
>   h(9) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
>   'libxml/xmlversion.h': No su ch file or directory
>
> D:\software\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown
>   distributio n option: 'bugtrack_url'
>
> warnings.warn(msg)
>
> error: command '"D:\software\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
>
> ----------------------------------------   Rolling back uninstall of lxml Cleaning up... Command D:\software\Python27\python.exe -c "import
>   setuptools;**file**='c:\user
>   s\x\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_x\lxml\setup.py';exec(compile(open(_
>   *file*_).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record c:\u sers\x\appdata\local\temp\pip-pyyuss-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-versio n-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\temp \pip_build_x\lxml Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "D:\software\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 9, in 
>       load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()   File "D:\software\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip__init__.py", line 148, in
>   ma in
>       return command.main(args[1:], options)   File "D:\software\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 169,
>   in  main
>       text = '\n'.join(complete_log) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 72: ordinal  not in range(128)

Comment: This is probably a problem with the C compiler, but I can't find a way to fix it

Comment: @user2091046, did you tried my answer? Can you please consider marking it as the correct one?

Answer (score 42):

If you have a compiler installed (tested with VS C++ 2008 Express), you can simply run:

`set STATICBUILD=true && pip install lxml`

As pointed out [on documentation](http://lxml.de/build.html#static-linking-on-windows), setting `STATICBUILD` will tell to lxml's installer to automatically download all its binary dependencies before build.

These `lxml` binary dependencies, that should be present when installing from source, will be downloaded and build together by the installer:

- libxslt
- iconv
- zlib
- libxml2

**Bonus**: It also works inside a virtualenv.

Comment: Hi @RYS, can you elaborate a bit more? What problems did you had with this solution? You already solved the issue? Can we offer any help?

Comment: I think OP and I were both having VS compiler issues (I was getting the same error code with a conda install). Ended up doing the `easy_install` solution described here, and that seemed to do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453986/easy-install-lxml-on-python-2-7-on-windows

Comment: You saved my day!

Answer (score 25):

This question is older but still pops up in google.  I tried the other answers to this question and they did not work for one reason or another and I did't want to track down and install all the dependencies to compile on Windows.

I noticed on pypi some of the lxml releases offer windows wheels and others do not.

So the simplest solution for me was to specify a version that did... i.e. `pip install lxml==3.6.0` since 3.6.0 offered a wheel while the newer 3.6.4 did not

Comment: This is what really worked for me after hours of searching. Best answer in case of windows!!

Comment: this worked for me. I was trying to install scrapy in a python 2.7 virtualenv on a windows OS, but was unable to because I couldnt install lxml. Thanks to you I finally figured it out!

Answer (score 16):

For your problem, there is a single line solution. Somehow, this is working  means suppose you are doing scraping at low level then this will work.

After 8 hours of research, I found this as working nothing else

```
pip install lxml==3.6.0
```

Nothing else is required.

All things above are applicable for Windows.

Comment if some other type of problem is persisting happy to help.

Here is my success after 8 hours:
[image: Here is my success after 8 hours]

Comment: Worked for me..Thanks!!

Comment: @KaushikNayak you can up vote this so that people don't waste their time on google searching for answers.

Answer (score 8):

You can do the steps from [Flak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22982239/790387), or you can simply [download the Windows installer](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml), double click to launch it, and be on your way.

Comment: In my experience, 1) you still often need to install the `VC2008 redistributables` if you don't already have them from let's say a MS Visual Studio or some prior app install that required them - have you ever experienced that/found that to be the case?  If not, any chance you already have them installed and didn't notice?  Also, 2) you need to install `python` separately from `lxml`. And finally, 3) I think the OP (@user2091046) is asking how to install/upgrade using `pip`

Comment: You don't need to install any developer tools if you use the installer, that's the whole point of it. You just need Python installed.

Comment: The installer worked for me, finally.  I had to reinstall Python (it didn't make its way into the registry the first time), and then I had to use the 32 bit lxml installer, despite running on a 64 bit system.

Comment: Your instructions helped although the page now offers *.whl files and not *.msi files. To install the *.whl I had to `pip install wheel` then after downloading the version for my platform, I did a `pip install lxml-3.4.3-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 4):

**These instructions are for Windows7 or Windows8 with Python2.7**.

**However**, they should work for various versions as the releases of python and other respective prerequisites change/evolve:

1. Install ***Python2.7***:

   1. Download the last release of Python2.7 (currently 2.7.6) from the downloads page [HERE](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-276/)

      - Direct link for Win32 MSI installer -> [HERE](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/python-2.7.6.msi)
      - Direct link for Win64 MSI installer -> [HERE](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/python-2.7.6.amd64.msi)
   2. Simply run the MSI to install python.  It will register itself in the registry, and appear in Add/REmove Programs.
   3. **NOTE:** my instructions that follow assume that you choose to install python to the default path of `C:\python27\` when asked during the Python Installation Wizard
2. Add the `C:\python27\` and `C:\python27\scripts` folders to the system path by adding those directories to the `PATH` environment variable from the **Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings link (Advanced Tab) > Environmental Variables (Button)**.
3. (OPTIONAL) Install ***OpenSSL***:

   1. Download **Win32 OpenSSL page** from [HERE](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) for your version of Windows and PC architecture
   2. Download **Visual C++ 2008 redistributables** for your version of Windows and PC architecture
   3. Download **OpenSSL** for your version of Windows and architecture (the regular version, not the light one)
   4. Add the following (depending on your architecture) directory (or wherever you insalled to) to your `PATH`, the same way you added `C:\python27` and `C:\python27\scripts` above:

      - **32-bit:**  `c:\openssl-win32\bin`
      - **64-bit:**  `c:\openssl-win64\bin`
4. Install ***Setuptools*** (`get-pip.py` should install Setuptools for you), but, just in case...

   1. Download `ez_setup.py` [HERE](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py) and save it in `C:\python27\scripts`
   2. Run **`C:\python27\scripts> python ez_setup.py`**
5. Install ***PIP***

   1. Download `get-pip.py` from [HERE](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) and save it in `C:\python27\scripts`
   2. Run **`C:\python27\scripts> python get-pip.py`**
6. Install ***LXML***

   1. Download `LXML 3.3.3` from [HERE](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.3.3) for your version of Windows and PC architecture
   2. Run the EXE file

Answer (score 3):

The FAQ's on the lxml website point to a site that has kindly created binary distributions for windows:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

the wheel can be installed using pip.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels

```
pip install lxml‑3.5.0‑cp27‑none‑win32.whl
```

Comment: Awesome, a page with a bunch of javascript: links

Comment: Click ovbiously work but its not ideal - as a work around if you inspect the link and then grab the dl function call from the href and run it in your console you can then see the URL of the download.

Comment: I don't trust binaries from somebody who would do something that nonsensical, so I found another solution (using the XML libraries that come with Python).

Comment: He is hosting it off his own servers and paying money for it so you can have the convenience, I figure he is attempting to reduce his bandwidth costs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install libxml, libxslt, libiconv and zlib in your virtual environment. You also need VS 2008, because python 2.7 is compiled against that version. I wrote a more detailed explanation here http://www.laurivan.com/install-lxml-on-windows-on-a-virtualenv/

Answer (score 1):

I have installed (VS C++ 2014 Express)
Direct pip install failed but after adding following borrowed from ***Fernando Macedo***
set STATICBUILD=true && pip install lxml
this worked for me in virtualenv on windows 10 with Python 3.5.2, lxml 3.6.4

```
    -tag cp35:
      Building lxml version 3.6.4.
      Building without Cython.
      ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external           command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
      ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

       Using build configuration of libxslt
       running bdist_wheel
       running build
       running build_py
       creating build
       creating build\lib.win32-3.5
       creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
       copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
       copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
       copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
       copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
       copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
       copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
       copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
       copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
       copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
       creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
     copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
     creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
     copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
     copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
     copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
     copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
     copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
     copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
     copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
     copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
     copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
     copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
     copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
     copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
     copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
     creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
     copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-     3.5\lxml\isoschematron
     copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
     copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
     copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
     copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
     copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
     copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
     copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
     copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
     copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.5
  creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\src\lxml
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc\lxml\includes "-Ic:\program files\python35-32\include" "-Ic:\program files\python35-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt" /Tcsrc\lxml\lxml.etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.obj -w
  cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
  lxml.etree.c
  src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
  Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  creating Users
  creating Users\DDSHARMA
  creating Users\DDSHARMA\AppData
  creating Users\DDSHARMA\AppData\Local
  creating Users\DDSHARMA\AppData\Local\Temp
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt" /TcC:\Users\DDSHARMA\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitsaig9hq_.c /FoUsers\DDSHARMA\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitsaig9hq_.obj
  xmlXPathInitsaig9hq_.c
  C:\Users\DDSHARMA\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitsaig9hq_.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
  *********************************************************************************
  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
  *********************************************************************************
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\ddsharma\documents\pymote_env\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DDSHARMA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-gtry8727\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\DDSHARMA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-waqsvkju-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\ddsharma\documents\pymote_env\include\site\python3.5\lxml:
    Building lxml version 3.6.4.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\src\lxml
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc\lxml\includes "-Ic:\program files\python35-32\include" "-Ic:\program files\python35-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt" /Tcsrc\lxml\lxml.etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.obj -w
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
    lxml.etree.c
    src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
    Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt" /TcC:\Users\DDSHARMA\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit1y_w6myc.c /FoUsers\DDSHARMA\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit1y_w6myc.obj
    xmlXPathInit1y_w6myc.c
    C:\Users\DDSHARMA\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit1y_w6myc.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    *********************************************************************************
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\ddsharma\documents\pymote_env\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DDSHARMA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-gtry8727\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\DDSHARMA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-waqsvkju-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\ddsharma\documents\pymote_env\include\site\python3.5\lxml" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\DDSHARMA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-gtry8727\lxml\

(pymote_env) C:\Users\DDSHARMA\Documents\pymote_env>set STATICBUILD=true && pip install lxml
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-3.6.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\DDSHARMA\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\c6\ad\ad\cd812eeb1e0e179b58d92b1e8bad7accd136f51b5d812fd495
Successfully built lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml
Successfully installed lxml-3.6.4

(pymote_env) C:\Users
```

\DDSHARMA\Documents\pymote_env>

Answer (score 0):

just follow the official instructions [lxml](https://lxml.de/installation.html)