# Having trouble installing lxml on Python 2.7

Tags: python, lxml

I ran the command line to install lxml but then it gave me this error:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-y6y867l_\lxml-3.5.0\temp\xmlXPathInit67jlgy6a.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory


Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
```

**Error:** `Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`

I also have MVC intstalled already. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), It contains many libraries, including lxml.

Answer (score 0):

Run this

```
set STATICBUILD=true && pip install lxml
```

And these dependencies will be downloaded and build together by the installer:

```
libxslt
iconv
zlib
libxml2
```

Or you can download the .whl file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml and install it by

```
pip install lxml‑3.5.0‑cp27‑none‑win32.whl
```

If it doesn't work,check this.
[lxml-install-on-windows-7-using-pip-and-python-2-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460890/lxml-install-on-windows-7-using-pip-and-python-2-7)

Hope this helps.