# How do I open a .whl binary installation file in CMD? Win Py 2.7 Err "No distributions at all found for lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win32.whl"

Tags: python-2.7, cmd, installation, lxml, libxml2

I've been at this for nearly 2 hours and I just can't seem to get my head around it. I am a novice Pythoner, it would appear. I am trying to intsall lxml, (needed to install scrapy). I have tried multiple methods (see my other current quesitons).

Currently I am trying the following.
I downloaded the lxml win 32 file for python 2.7 from this website:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.4.4#downloads
The LXML Binaries are also available here: "http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml"

I download the .whl file.

I then open up CMD, and CD to my download folder. Once in that folder I run the following command (as per the answer to this question here: [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file))

```
pip install lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

This is the output:

```
C:\Users\Charles\Downloads\python>pip install lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win32.whl
Downloading/unpacking lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win32.whl
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement lxml-3.4.4-cp27-    none
-win32.whl
No distributions at all found for lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win32.whl
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log
```

Can anyone help me figure out what this means/what is going on? How can I execute this file to install the lxml as needed?
Many thanks!!

Edit: I am using Windows 64 bit, but from this question here: "[easy_install lxml on Python 2.7 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453986/easy-install-lxml-on-python-2-7-on-windows)" the file I have selected appears to be the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Windows 64 bit and use Scrapy.  It took a while for me to figure out the best way to set up my virtualenv because lxml would not simply pip install.

So I did somethine very similar to what you did but it looks at first glance we may just be using different sites.  So try downloading this .whl from [HERE](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml). Specifically, for your specifications I believe, grab the one that reads

> lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl

and then just cd to the downloads folder and `pip install lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is upgrade `pip`; the latest version is 8.0. Next, you need to install wheel support (this step may be redundant in later versions) and then finally install your wheel:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install wheel
```

`lxml` needs a lot of source-level dependencies, which are difficult to install in Windows. This is why the project provides binary installers for Windows. You can download these from the [pypi page for lxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.4.4). Make sure you choose the right version for your environment:

- `lxml-3.4.4.win32-py2.7.exe` - for Python 2.7 running on Windows 32-bit
- `lxml-3.4.4.win32-py3.2.exe` - for Python 3.2 running on Windows 32-bit
- `lxml-3.4.4.win-amd64-py2.7.exe` - for Python 2.7, running on Windows 64-bit